# How can I align items left while keeping them in a column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I am trying to align items left while keeping them in a column, however, when I put items in a column, it defaults to re-centering the items on the page.

Here's what I have:

**HTML**

```
<div className='postHeader'> 
   <div>{post.title}</div>
   <div>{post.author}</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.postHeader {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Here no need of padding instead of you use flex-basis:  or flex: .If still you're not getting then post the snippet of your code.

Answer (score 4):

The alignment in the *cross-axis* (when you have a *column* `flexbox` this is the horizontal axis) is determined by the property `align-items`. (the default value is `stretch` which causes the flex items to extend all the way to the end of the flexbox container)

Set `align-items: flex-start` - see demo below:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.postHeader {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class='postHeader'>
  <div>{post.title}</div>
  <div>{post.author}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `text-align` property specifies the horizontal alignment of text in an element.

```
text-align:left
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more property in your CSS snippet with `align-items: flex-start`

**HTML**

```
<div className='postHeader'> 
   <div>{post.title}</div>
   <div>{post.author}</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.postHeader {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start; /* ADDED */
}
```

Comment: That _exact same_ answer was given 50 min. before you gave yours, so why do we need 2 ?